# Loop iterating too fast, Pause until next window avalible

Tags: c#, api

I'm using a C# While loop and a data reader to send updates that pull information through a web based API. With our subscription I can only send one request every 30 seconds, but I need to fire the request every 30 seconds so we get all the responses in time.

I am implementing my loop as below:

```
while (Reader.Read()) {
API_Process(Reader["country"].ToString(), Reader["appStore"].ToString(),     
        Reader["GameType"].ToString(), Reader["RankType"].ToString());
}
```

Any Suggestions? I'm almost desperate enough to shove in a sleep command, but that seems really inappropriate. Given a choice between to long a delay and insufficient delay, to long will win out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to queue your requests then you could use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the desired interval. The OS will wake your thread when the timer expires and you can get pretty decent resolution at 30 seconds.

P.S. Your code is not *recursing* - it's just iterating (your title is misleading).

Comment: My Bad. Im forever confusing the two terms.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably be back to find more informatino no how best to use the timer, but this seems to be about right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Task.Delay` like this:

```
async Task DoUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (Reader.Read()) {
       var delay = Task.Delay(30000, token);

       API_Process(Reader["country"].ToString(), Reader["appStore"].ToString(),     
                Reader["GameType"].ToString(), Reader["RankType"].ToString());

       await delay;
    }
}
```